# How do I dynamically set a type?

Tags: c++, class, templates, generics

I have been trying to write code that reads and inits a graph from a text input file.

Now, a graph is a template class `Graph<K, V>`, where `K` is the type of the nodes' key and `V` is the type of the nodes' value.

Let's say I want to take a Graph in input from a text file of such form:

```
char;int    // the types
a;b;c       // the keys
a;b,32;c,5  // edges starting from a
b;c,2       // edges starting from b
```

How do I store the type in a variable so to init the graph?

I would like to do something like this:

```
getline(file, value, ';');
string keyTypeString = value;
getline(file, value);
string valueTypeString = value;

type keyType = ...
type valueType = ...

Graph<keyType, valueType> graph = ...
```

How do I do that in C++? Is it even possible?

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language, types are set at time of compilation and can't be changed at run-time. So no, what you want to do is not possible, you have to come up with another way of solving your problem.

Comment: No it is not. At least not the way you imagine. The types a template is instantiated with are static, decided during compilation long before any file is opened.

Comment: You have to use an object which can store different types. Take a look at boost::any

Comment: If your program doesn't do anything meaningful with the labels beyond comparing and printing them, just always use `Graph<std::string,std::string>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know at compile time all *possible* `type`s then use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html). There are plenty of examples in the docs, but essentially you will have something like:

```
using type = boost::variant<char, int>;

std::string input;
std::getline(file, input);

type value;

try {
    value = boost::lexical_cast<int>(input);
} catch(const boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
    value = input.front(); // char
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible directly. C++ is a statically typed language. You should use a specific container able to store values whatever it's type. Take a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any.html.

example from boost site :

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using boost::any_cast;
typedef std::list<boost::any> many;

void append_int(many & values, int value)
{
    boost::any to_append = value;
    values.push_back(to_append);
}

void append_string(many & values, const std::string & value)
{
    values.push_back(value);
}

void append_char_ptr(many & values, const char * value)
{
    values.push_back(value);
}

void append_any(many & values, const boost::any & value)
{
    values.push_back(value);
}

void append_nothing(many & values)
{
    values.push_back(boost::any());
}
```

So in your case, you can have a `Graph<keyType, boost::any>` graph. You should store somewhere which type is stored in your graph. But you will use a `switch case` statement at a moment when you have to deal with concrete type

Answer (score 0):

## No

In C++ this is not possible. Templates are a *compile time* construct. In other languages the same problem set is solved by a different construct they call "generics" where it is possible at runtime, but with templates in C++, it's not.